# Given finite set $S$, is there a name for a set of maps $M:S \to S$ such that for any $x,y \in S$, there is a sequence of maps taking $x$ to $y\,$?

Tags: functions, terminology

> Is there a name for a set of mappings $M:S \to S$ such that for any $x$ and $y$ in finite set $S$, there is a sequence of mappings that takes $x$ to $y\,$?

I hope the question is understandable without further explanation.  It seems kind of basic.  If necessary, I could give an example.

Comment: transitive? ${}$

Comment: I recommend to include as much detail as you can to avoid your question being closed.

Comment: A group action on a set is called transitive if there exists elements that take $x$ to $y$ for all $x,y \in S$.

Comment: I would guess that "there is a sequence of mappings that takes x to y" is intended to mean "there is a sequence of mappings in M whose composition takes x to y."

Comment: Yes that is what I meant.  Sorry for any confusion.